# display fullcalendar under input field after click it

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar 6, what I want is: user click a input field, then fullcalendar displayed under this input field(that is fullcalendar tied to an input field), just like jquery ui datepicker. how could I do that?

Comment: Yes that is certainly possible. It doesn't really work like a datepicker though, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @ADyson how could I do that? I didn't find the solution from the doc.

Comment: You can use the `render()` function of the calendar to show it in response to some event